# Show all items in a byte list starting from index

Tags: c#, .net

I've a byte list `List<Byte> oldList` and need a new list starting from a specific index like:

```
List<Byte> newList= new List<byte>();
int index = 5;
...
```

How can I do that?

Comment: List<Byte> sublist =oldlist.GetRange(5,oldlist.Count);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `Skip` method

```
List<Byte> sublist = oldList.Skip(index).ToList();
```

Or `List<T>` has also a `GetRange` method:

```
List<Byte> sublist = oldList.GetRange(index, oldList.Count - index);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Case,Index=5,So You can use GetRange():

> List sublist =oldlist.GetRange(5,(oldlist.Count)-1);

Comment: this will give you an ArgumentException because of the Count.